# Can't Send Email With Network.Mail.SMTP

Tags: email, haskell

I've been reading through the documentation for [Network.Mail.SMTP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/smtp-mail-0.1.4.6) to send an e-mail. My problem comes after the code begins to run I get a message saying

> socket 11: Data.ByteString.hGetLine end of file

When I check the inbox folder for the recipient's email and the sent folder of the sending email, there is no message being sent. What can I do to make this code do it's job. I've posted the code and omitted some of the sensitive sections.

```
import Network.Mail.Mime

import Network.Mail.SMTP

import qualified Data.Text as T

import qualified Data.ByteString as B

import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

mFrom = Address (Just $ T.pack "FirstName LastName") (T.pack "Sender's Email")

mTo = [Address Nothing (T.pack "Recipient Email")]

mCC = []

mBCC = []

mHeader = [(B.empty, (T.pack "Test Header"))]

pType = T.empty

pEncoding = None

pFilename = Nothing

pHeader = [(B.empty, T.pack "Test Part Header")]

pContent = BL.empty

pPart = Part pType pEncoding pFilename pHeader pContent

alternative =[pPart]

mParts = [alternative]

mMail = Mail mFrom mTo mCC mBCC mHeader mParts

a = sendMailWithLogin' "smtp.gmail.com" 465 "Sender Email" "Sender Password" mMail

main = a
```

Comment: Have you tried using an empty list instead of your current definition of,`mParts`

Comment: Just tried it out, no change in result though.

Comment: Did you try to use `simpleMail'` ?

Comment: Tried it out, still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the error, but honestly I don't know why this is happening, maybe it has to do with encryption, which I guess google forbids not to have (but that is just a guess).

But since I remembered having sent some email with haskell in the past - I dug out some old code: note this uses [HaskellNet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad (when)
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import Network.HaskellNet.SMTP.SSL

main :: IO ()
main = bracket
         (connectSMTPSSL "smtp.gmail.com")
         closeSMTP $ \conn ->
           do success <- authenticate LOGIN
                                      "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
                                      "password"
                                      conn
              when success
                   $ sendPlainTextMail "to" "from" "Test" "test" conn
```

the usage is pretty straightforward establish a connection, authenticate over it send your email, if you have attachments use `sendMimeMail` or `sendMimeMail'` or if you want to use the existing `Mail` type you already built use `sendMimeMail2`.

If you haven't seen `bracket` it is the (quite elegant) haskell variant of `try..finally` - it simply makes sure that the connection is closed.

Comment: So I copied/pasted this into my editor and replaced everything with its true value and ran it. It runs without error but no email is sent. Is there something I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You can change the when to an `if success then..else..` and check if the authentication fails